# 1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax | Getting an error with the PyMySQL update process

Tags: python-3.x, pymysql

I want to get the column name from the variable.

I ran this query and got an error message:

**Query**

```
sql = "UPDATE `xxx` SET %s=1 WHERE user_id=%s"
sonuc = pen.execute(sql, (gcn, userid))
db.commit()
```

**Error**

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '6=1 WHERE user_id=1' at line 1")
```

Comment: Please share more details - setting a variable column name is usually not supported in prepared statements